# XML: Is this valid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, declaration

Is the following XML declaration valid?

```
<message metadata="SomeMetaData" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

where `xsi` is defined as "`http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`"

If I am trying to create the above data for transfer through a ASP.NET Web Service Application in C#, how do I go about coding the above?

Say for example I have a web service method written in C# called

```
SomeMethod(Msg someMessage)
```

How to I indicate that the `message` field found in class `Msg` contains an attribute called `metadata` and that the field `message` itself is also an element which can be `null`(contains no data as shown in following example)?

```
<message metadata="SomeMetaData"></message>
```

In other cases, it can contain some data as follows:

```
<message metadata="SomeMetaData">
    <data>1234</data>
    <data>5678</data>
</message>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML is valid, provided that the "xsi" namespace is defined.

What do you mean by "create the above data"?  Example?

Comment: I have updated the question. Is it possible to do away with xsi:nil="true"?

Comment: It depends on the requirements of the web service you're calling, right?